# Valid ESTA for US, but Check-In online says "Not received travel approval from the US authorities. Contact US Embassy or Consulate"

Tags: usa, esta, switzerland, new-york-city, check-in

Tomorrow I want to fly to New York with my family.
I have a valid ESTA for 2 years and have never been to the US.

After filling out the information in the online check-in the following was written: "Unfortunately, we have not received travel approval from the US authorities for MYNAME. Contact US Embassy or Consulate."

This message only refers to me and I don't understand why I got it.
I've been travelling for 20 years.

Did this ever happen to anybody? 
Should I call the US Embassy or deal with this at the airport? I've already booked hotels, a car etc. and I don't understand why I get this message.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I strongly recommend to contact the consulate or embassy immediately.

Comment: While you wait for the consulate’s reply, Maybe try removing the information from the airlines website and adding it again? Essentially a retry? You never know it could be a server communication error.

Comment: Afaik you can check the status of your ESTA on the [CBP web site](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/).

Comment: Double check your data (passport number, country) and your ESTA number. Did you used the official website for ESTA? There are many scam site for ESTA. Check again your ESTA email

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies. I did check my ESTA status again and it says "Authorization approved". Can they still deny me entry to the flight even when I have a valid ESTA?

Comment: You should have contacted the embassy more than an hour ago. The instant you saw that message. Do it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks, yes I called. The embassy told me that when my ESTA is valid there shouldn't be any problems. So I called the airline and they told me that they will check when I'm there :)

Comment: Is this a very recently issued ESTA? Perhaps someone who knows more than me could comment on the possibility that whatever system the airlines use might be a couple of days out of date?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify question in comments. Putting on hold for now.